# PostgreSQL store not if row is not unique plus value is already stored in other column

Tags: postgresql

I want to store

```
INSERT INTO dining_table_grouping 
            (layout_id, 
             dining_table_id, 
             master_dining_table_id, 
             start_timestamp, 
             end_timestamp)
VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
```

only if dining_table_id and master_dining_table_id values are unique in both, the dining_table_id and in the master_dining_table_id column, which only applies if the others layout_id, dining_table_id, start_timestamp and end_timestamp are not unique.

So for example:

```
VALUES(1, 2, 3, 2019-03-13 08:00:00, 2019-03-13 09:00:00)
VALUES(5, 4, 2, 2019-03-13 07:00:00, 2019-03-13 10:00:00)
```

cannot be stored, because 2 is already stored in the dining_table_id column.

How can I achieve that?

My try:

```
INSERT INTO dining_table_grouping(layout_id, dining_table_id, master_dining_table_id, start_timestamp, end_timestamp)
           VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5)
           WHERE NOT dining_table_id OR master_dining_table_id = $3 AND dining_table_id OR master_dining_table_id = $4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a SELECT statement instead of VALUES and a condition with NOT EXISTS:

```
insert into dining_table_grouping (
  layout_id, 
  dining_table_id, 
  master_dining_table_id, 
  start_timestamp, 
  end_timestamp)
select $1, $2, $3, $4, $5
where not exists (
  select 1 from dining_table_grouping
  where 
    (layout_id = $1 and start_timestamp = $4 and end_timestamp = $5)
    or dining_table_id in ($2, $3) or master_dining_table_id in ($2, $3)
);
```

Comment: What if I want to add a condition to not exists. So that it only applies if `layout_id`, `start_timestamp` and `end_timestamp` is not unique. I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: This is a totally different requirement. Post a new question explaining what you want and provide sample data and expected results.